# How to set user.is_staff to True by default in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I need to set the is_staff value to True when creating a user in Admin interface.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: "difficult to tell", aha

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define a custom ModelAdmin and add your custom logic there:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            obj.is_staff = True
            obj.save()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

Comment: Glad to help :] don't forget to accept the answer d: